# Nhibernate dialect and driver to use for connecting to a sybase database in .net

Tags: c#, nhibernate, driver, sybase, dialect

In version 2 of Nhibernate, I had it working with below fluent nhibernate configuration:

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseAdoNet12Dialect,NHibernate</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SybaseAdoNet12ClientDriver</property>
```

Now I want to use the Nhibernate 3.1 version and both the above dialect and driver are missing.

I am a little confused. I see there is a dialect SybaseASA9Dialect but I could not find out what driver goes with it.

There is also a lot of blogs about using the sqlanywhere implementation, but it requires adding the dlls like iAnywhere.Data.SAClient from sybase which have licenses attached to it and makes my problem bigger.

Can someone give me a simple dialect, driver configuration to use with the nhibernate 3.1 for connecting to sybase?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey Vishal, it seems to me; that you have solve your problem: I am having the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608910/connect-to-sybase-iq-with-nhibernate maybe you can give me a tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only say that drivers are:

```
NHibernate.Driver.SybaseAsaClientDriver
NHibernate.Driver.SybaseAseClientDriver
NHibernate.Driver.SybaseSQLAnywhereDriver
```

And dialects are:

```
NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseSQLAnywhere10Dialect
NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseSQLAnywhere11Dialect
```

This is in 3.2, but I think in 3.1 should be the same.

Comment: Thanks Michele, that is pointing in the right direction. From the nhibernate docs for 3.2 I figured I have to use dialect specific to my sybase server. Here are the specifications from http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html

Comment: Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise 15 NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect                         Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere 9 NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseASA9Dialect                           Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere 10 NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseASA10Dialect                          Sybase SQL Anywhere 10                                              Hibernate.Dialect.SybaseSQLAnywhere10Dialect                  Sybase SQL Anywhere 11  NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseSQLAnywhere11Dialect