# connect to Sybase IQ with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sap-iq

I want to connect to a Sybase IQ database, which is lying on a server via Fluent NHibernate: I use C# with the NHibernate version 3.3.1.4

I am using the code from here:
http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/nhibernate-session-handling-in-aspnet-the-easy-way/

I have tried to adopt the construktor to this:

```
private SessionManager()
{
    sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(SQLAnywhereConfiguration.SQLAnywhere11.ConnectionString("server=SERVER_NAME:PORT; user=USER_NAME; password=PASSWORD; database=DATABASE"))
   .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionManager>())
   .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "managed_web"))
   .BuildConfiguration()
   .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

I get no connection to my database; does I use the right connection string, or is the SQLAnywhereConfiguration class wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-advantage/
or http://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-adaptive/
to check your connection string format.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, do you have more experience with Sybase IQ and Nhibernate, would be great, if you can help me.